# Eliminate Author name from Body class from wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Is there any way to eliminate Author name from body_class(); ? is there any specific filter available remove only author name from body class ?

Please help me on this

Comment: Why would one want to do that?

Comment: because we dont need to display Author name in body class some author name having 'span"  eg : one author name is 'riaspan' so bootstrap default class [*span] is applying for body class so paging is breaking ,

Answer (score 0):

You can remove classes from the body_class() function by adding a filter in your functions.php file. In your case the 'author' class.

```
add_filter('body_class', function (array $classes) {
   if (in_array('author', $classes)) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('author', $classes)] );
   }
   return $classes;
});
```

You can find the whole list of classes names references at
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/ and check more details from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

You could also look for a specific class name result and replace it. You have two: one with the author-name and one with the author-id. The following replaces the name 'bob' in author-name with author-hello

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'replace_author_bob_name' );
function replace_author_bob_name( $classes ) {
  // You have all the classes in $classes
  // Replaces author-bob with author-hello
  $new_classes = array();
  foreach($classes as $cls) {
  
    if ($cls == "author-bob") $new_classes[] = "author-hello";
    else $new_classes[] = $cls;
  }
  return $new_classes;
}
```